# Interpret integral symbolically

Tags: symbolic

I am trying to calculate the integral of an symbolic function f[x] and want it to be symbolically $\int f(x) dx = F[x]$.
I tried defining it implicitly via

```
F'[x_] = f[x];
```

This works fine in one direction as

```
D[F[b], b]
```

gives

```
f[b].
```

However, the otherway round doesn't work as the input `Integrate[f[b], b]` translates to $\int f(x) dx$ instead of `F[b]`.

I also tried defining `Integrate[f[x],x]=F[x]`, but this is protected.

Do you have any suggestions on how to get this working? I couldn't find anything in the documentation - I'm happy for hints in case I missed something.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `Integrate[f'[x], x]`?

Comment: @march Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure how this helps. The goals is not to arrive at the output `f[x]` by any means but to have Input `Integrate[f[x],x]`, Output `F[x]`.
Could you maybe clarify what you mean by your suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by saying "*I am trying to calculate the integral of an symbolic function*"? do you intend to write eg a function that calculates the integrals of its inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you probably want. Associate `UpValues` with the symbols `f` and `F` as follows:

```
ClearAll[f, F]
f /: Integrate[f[x_], x_] := F[x]
F /: D[F[x_], x_] := f[x]
```

Then,

```
Integrate[f[t], t]
D[F[t], t]
(* F[t] *)
(* f[t] *)
```

Comment: Works fine for my purpose, but note that `Integrate[a*f[x],x]` does not give `aF[x]`. Altering the expression even by simple multiplication messes everything up.